# Why does my car run go through obstacles only head on?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

My player car has rigid body and a mesh collider against a mesh collider road barrier. When I slide against the barrier, the car stays within the road. When I hit the car head on, it goes through the barrier and sometimes flips.

I don't really want to mess around with the sizes of the car or the barrier as it will look too unrealistic.

I already changed the car to continuous, continuous dynamic, and continuous speculative but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: could you illustrate what you mean by "going through"? are you sure you're not using `Trasform.translate` for the movement of the player?

Comment: The car doesn't bounce off the wall. I wish I could upload a picture, but it's supposed to bounce off the wall. However, it just enters through the barrier. I am using `Transform.translate` for the movement of the car ... should I use something else?

Comment: yes, you should using rigidbody motion. use rigidbody's velocity and acceleration to move your car instead of just translating it, because while just translating, the physics wouldn't be applied to the body

Comment: Geeky is correct.  It is recommended to use AddForce for rigid bodies rather than manipulate transforms directly.  That way Unity can handle collisions and rebound for you with zero code. Now this isn’t always the case as sometimes it can be useful.  Such as a teleporting car that materialises halfway through a barrier.  :)

Answer (score 0):

As others stated, first consider applying forces over Transform.Translate for this movement scenario.  However, sometimes, I want to add my own animations when things touch when using Transform.Translate to drive the asset.

I do the following within OnTriggerEnter to prevent odd flips from the physics engine and to control the response the collision causes:

1. Use the OnTriggerEnter to detect when it collides.
2. Freeze rotation so I can control how it rotates.
3. Apply a force to create the reaction I'd like in the opposite direction.
4. Move it around with FixedUpdate for a desired time.

```
    public class DroneScript : MonoBehaviour {
        bool backup = false; float backup_timer;
        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {   // first, look at the thing it collided with to ensure I want
            // to trigger my own response to the collision.
            if (other.tag == "Structure" && other.gameObject.name != "Floor")
            {   // then set a timer and a flag (backup) that will allow a period of my own response
                // to execute within FixedUpdate().
                backup = true; backup_timer = Time.time + 1.0f;
                
                // Apply a force to get my desired affect (push up and back)
                rb.freezeRotation = false; 
                rb.AddForce(transform.up * 1.0f, ForceMode.Impulse);
                rb.AddForce(transform.forward * -0.25f, ForceMode.Impulse);

                main_script.PlayDroneSound("bonk",.5f,false); //custom sound for initial collision
            } 
        }
        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            if (backup)
            {
                if (backup_timer > Time.time) // do this stuff per our time desired
                {
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0), Time.deltaTime*5f);
                }
                else {
                    backup = false; //reset the flag
                    main_script.PlayDroneSound("bink", .5f,false);//custom sound for the end of my resposne.
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0), 0); // rotate like I want it to look
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity=Vector3.zero;
                    rb.freezeRotation = true; // I want to control how it rotates after it collides.
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```